# OSX / Unix: move odd or even numbered files

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, unix

I have a folder with a range of numbered files (camera images) and I'd like to move every other image into a different folder, so either all the odd numbered images, or all the even ones. How can I do this using unix commands?

```
  IMG_0001.CR2 [move this]
IMG_0002.CR2
  IMG_0003.CR2 [move this]
IMG_0004.CR2
  IMG_0005.CR2 [move this]
IMG_0006.CR2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
mkdir odd; mv *[13579].CR2 odd
```

Comment: How does this work? And how can it be modified to rename even-numbered files to have a name that is one less than whatever value it currently is? (ie. rename 002.txt to 001.txt, 010.txt to 009.txt, etc.)

Comment: The renaming looks like another problem, I would recomend to ask a separate question as it may be interesting for another people too.

Comment: Does work in 2023